# VLookup, Index Match, Lookup not working correctly

Tags: google-sheets

I thought I was doing the formula correctly using index-match but it's giving the wrong answer.  I also tried a VLOOKUP, MATCH, and LOOKUP and still not getting the correct answer.  I have a range with ID's and then names.  In another column, I just have ID's not in any order.  I am trying to match the names with the ID's from the first range.  It seems pretty straight forward, but it keeps giving me incorrect names.  I have searched with all of the above formulas, and I am pretty sure I did it right, but I know I am missing something. Thank you in advance for the help!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aX3Ljy_PIwIT5HAxqI-YcTO-vxNAMO4RNcYL3kAqAEU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `,0` at the end of MATCH to find an exact match. If not it will find a similar one. If not you can change MATCH with XMATCH whose option by default is exact match!

See: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12406049?hl=en-GB

Comment: When I tried that I got this error message: #N/A  Did not find '260576' in MATCH evaluation.  That's why I am confused.

Comment: Ohhh, I see, you have `A1:A12` instead of `A1:A121` - then it won't find it. Adjust the range and the 0 in MATCH and it will work!

Comment: Thank you once again!  I knew I missed something easy and couldn't figure out why.  Sorry- I should have seen it, but thank you!!!

Comment: It happens! I'm glad it was useful!